# Solving $\frac{\phi_1}{\phi_2}=\frac{\frac{\phi_1}{\phi_1d+\phi_2(1-d)}}{\frac{1-\phi_1}{(1-\phi_1)d+(1-\phi_2)(1-d)}}$ for $d$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose I have the following constraints:

- $0 \leq \phi_1 \leq 1$
- $0 \leq \phi_2 \leq 1$
- $0 \leq \delta \leq 1$

Now, suppose I have the following equations:

$$ \frac{\phi_1}{\phi_2} = 
\frac{\frac{\phi_1}{\phi_1\delta + \phi_2(1-\delta)}}{\frac{1-\phi_1}{(1-\phi_1)\delta + (1 - \phi_2)(1-\delta)}}$$

**My Question:**

- Is it possible to solve this equation to get $\delta$ in terms of $\phi_1$,  $\phi_2$ ?
- In general, is it possible to determine if smaller values of $\delta$ make the LHS (Left Hand Side) and RHS (Right Hand Side) of this equation closer to each other ... and if larger values of $\delta$ make the LHS and RHS further from each other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OP here.

I think I found my own answer to this question.

After doing some algebra, I got:

$$\delta = \frac{\phi_2}{(1-\phi_1) + \phi_2}$$

Is this correct?